# Animating Polygon with Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, geometry, fabricjs

I am trying to get the polygon animation working for Fabric.js to work. The demo is [here](http://fabricjs.com/polygon-animation), but the code does not run even on the Fabric.js website. I've tried fabric.utils.animate and Polygon.animate, and neither seem to work. They work for moving, or rotating animations, but not for transforming the actual anchor points. Has anyone had success animating a polygon in this way?

Answer (score 0):

here is the working fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/noj3cy10/

it work in prev version of `fabric.js 1.5.0`